# Want suggestion to create UI in flutter using dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone I am new to the flutter framework. I am trying to implement UI as given in the image below. As of now consider this is a static UI component. Want to build this using a flutter widget only.

I wanted to know is there any way I can create this type of UI in a flutter. As I am new in flutter how long it will take to learn flutter so that I will be able to create this kind of UI.

I tried creating the same UI in a flutter as I am an angular developer so I thought if I can do it quickly. But I am not able to do it. 
My main concern is

1)Is this feasible and if yes 
2)How much time will require for new flutter developer

[image]

Your suggestion highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but why is the [tag:angular] there ? I am removing it as we really can not help you there.

Comment: can explain in more detail what the image is showing. Looks like some type of calendar/timeline view.

Comment: There are 2 timelines . One is horizontal and vertical timeline. Horizontal time line would contain different type of icon with details.Like on click of black icon it will open vertical child timelines where there are user list like icons with more details and action we can perform on popup of particular user icon click. As of now you can consider this as a static UI.